# Kohana helpers do not work

Tags: php, kohana

I am completely new to the world on PHP frameworks. I have been trying to make helpers work all morning but they refuse to do so. Do I need to somehow enable them? Or install them?

When I do:

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_Api extends Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {
        echo url::base();
    }
```

Go to:

```
myurl/api
```

I get:

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Class 'Url' not found

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since version 3.3 class names are case-sensitive, so what you're after is:

```
echo URL::base();
```